# Looking for the best way to build centralized authentication for multiple websites

Tags: node.js, authentication

Long story short, i have a couple of clients who wanted to manage some stuff on their website, all websites are build with `nodejs`.

I'v built a small CMS for those websites.

Keep in mind that none of my websites https,
here is what i want to happen:

- a client goes to **my** website and submits a form with his password and username
- i http **POST** his credentials to **his** website
- **his** website returns a json with **OK 200** if the credentials are ok

questions:

- Is this the best way to do it ?
- what encryption method should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not the best way to do it.
You should never authenticate through http, and you should definitely not do you own encryption between the server and the clients. Please consider using SSL.
You can get a wildcard SSL certificate which supports subdomains and thus multiple websites, like:
x.example.com
y.example.com
z.example.com

This is a recurring question, and the answer will always be to use established technologies and algorithms, instead of reinventing the wheel and possibly introducing security holes of your own.

Please see this [article](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/) on javascript cryptography and why not to do it.

But when you have the website wrapped in SSL you can use the approach you explained and it will then be secure.

Comment: what do you mean by `x.example.com`, is `example.com` my website and `x.example.com` the client website ? could you explain further on the best way to do it ? or just refer me to an answer...

Comment: Yes I intended example.com to be your website and imagined that xyz.example.com would be your clients websites. If they have their own domain names, you will need an SSL certificate for each domain.

The best way to do it is to use SSL encryption. You need an SSL Certificate which you can buy for each domain. When the website is secured by SSL you can build a login form just like you described, but it is important that the form is sent using SSL to secure the username and password of the users.

https://www.digicert.com/ssl.htm

Comment: thanks! you should probably edit your answer, the best way to go is just like i said but using `ssl`.